# How to get each node's attribute via xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

How can I get each node's attribute via xpath?

For instance,

book.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<records timestamp="1264777862">
<record></record>
<record></record>
<record timestamp="1264777000"></record>
<record></record>
</records>
```

php,

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;

$doc->load('book.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

# get and output "<entry>" elements
$x = $doc -> getElementsByTagName('record');

# Count the total feed with xpath.
$total = $x->length;

# the query is relative to the records node
$query = 'string(/records/@timestamp)';

for ($i=0; $i<$total; $i++)
{
    $timestamp = $xpath->evaluate($query,$x->item($i));
    echo $timestamp ."<br/>";
}

?>
```

result (which it loops the first node only),

```
1264777862
1264777862
1264777862
1264777862
```

But I want to get,

```
1264777862
1264777000
```

I have followed the question and answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162986/xpath-get-root-node-attributes) and modified from it.

Or maybe there are better methods?

**EDIT:**

xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<records>
    <record timestamp="1264777862">A</record>
    <record>B</record>
    <record timestamp="1264777000">C</record>
    <record>D</record>
</records>
```

with this,

```
for ($i=0; $i<$total; $i++)
{
    $value = $x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $timestamp = $xpath->evaluate($query,$x->item($i));
    echo $value.': '.$timestamp ."<br/>";
}
```

I get this result,

```
A: 1264777862
B: 1264777862
C: 1264777862
D: 1264777862
```

but this is the result I am after,

```
A: 1264777862
B: 
C: 1264777862
D:
```

**EDIT:**

a test,

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//records/record');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $value = $node->nodeValue;
    $timestamp = $node->getAttribute('timestamp');
    echo $value .': '."<br/>";
}
```

result,

```
A: 
B: 
C: 
D:
```

Comment: Your XML has an attribute on `records` and one on `record`. Which are you trying to work with?

Comment: sorry my mistake. please see my edit above. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//records[@timestamp]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $timestamp = $node->getAttribute('timestamp');
}
```

Though, you've mixed `record` and `records` in your example, so I'm not sure which you're using in reality.

---

update:  This code works for me:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<EOL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<records>
    <record timestamp="1264777862">A</record>
    <record>B</record>
    <record timestamp="1264777000">C</record>
    <record>D</record>
</records>
EOL;

$x = new DOMDocument();
$x->loadXML($xml);

$xp = new DOMXpath($x);

$nodes = $xp->query('//records/record');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
   echo $node->nodeValue, ': ', $node->getAttribute('timestamp'), "\n";
}
```

and outputs

```
A: 1264777862
B:
C: 1264777000
D:
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake. please see my edit above. I get an error message with `getAttrribute` thanks.

Comment: woops. typo. Should be getAttribute (one r).

Comment: sorry, I just realised another problem as I need more information in the result. I cannot use the query u in your answer I guess. can u please see my edit above? thanks.

Comment: So you want to output all `record` nodes, whether they have a timestamp attribute or not? Use `//records` as the xpath, then `$node->nodeValue` to get the a/b/c/d stuff.

Comment: how can I use `getAttribute('timestamp')` after that? please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: sorry, my mistake again for forgetting echo `$timestamp`! thanks.